# Is $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ Decreasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

It's evident that the sequence $$a_n=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ is a Decreasing Sequence from $n \ge 3$ And it converges to its infimum $1$.

We know that if a sequence is monotone decreasing and bounded it converges to infimum.

But in this sequence first three terms increase and then decrease. Is it treated as a Decreasing Sequence?

Comment: It's an "eventually decreasing" sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $n^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n}$ and find the monotonicity of $g(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$.

Comment: Then prove more than the stated question.  Show that $x^{1/x}$ is a decreasing function (on an appropriate domain).

Comment: Yeap, of course one can do so. It is also possible to imitate the proof that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ to show that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is decreasing from a point and over.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no problem in finding the limit by ignoring the first two terms and the limit just happens to be the infimum of the sequence.  But in general the limit may not be the infimum. If $a_k \geq a_{k+1}\geq a_{k+2},...$  ($a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$) then the limit may be different from  infimum as seen in the example $1,2,2+\frac 1 3,2+\frac  1 4,2+\frac  15...$. Here the limit is $2$ and the infimum is $1$.